# NameError: name 'img2' is not define. OpenCV Augmented Reality

Tags: python, opencv

Hello I'm getting an error of NameError: name 'img2' is not defined in line 42. At first I thought it was an indentation problem but now I think it has something to do with the matrix because it did not display the needed information and that caused img2 to become undefined if I try to call on the matrix variable. I tried everything and there are only so many things I could do as a beginner.

Here's my full code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
myVid = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
imgTarget = cv2.imread("TargetImage.jpg")

success, imgVideo = myVid.read()
hT, wT, cT = imgTarget.shape
imgVideo = cv2.resize(imgVideo, (wT, hT))

orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=200)

kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(imgTarget, None)

while True:
    success, imgWebcam = cap.read()
    imgAug = imgWebcam.copy()
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(imgWebcam, None)

    bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
    matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)
    good = []
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance:
            good.append(m)
    print(len(good))

    imgFeatures = cv2.drawMatches(imgTarget, kp1, imgWebcam, kp2, good, None, flags=2)

    if len(good) > 15:
        srcPts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        dstPts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        matrix, mask = cv2.findHomography(srcPts, dstPts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
        print(matrix)

        pts = np.float32([[0,0],[0,hT],[wT,hT],[wT,0]]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,matrix)
        
        img2 = cv2.polylines(imgWebcam,[np.int32(dst)],True,(255,0,255),3, cv2.LINE_AA)

    cv2.imshow('img2', img2)
    cv2.imshow('ImgFeatures', imgFeatures)
    cv2.imshow('ImgTarget', imgTarget)
    cv2.imshow('myVid', imgVideo)
    cv2.imshow('Webcam', imgWebcam)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving a name error because the `img2` object doesn't exist. `img2` is being defined inside an `if`-statement, where if the condition that the length of good is less than or equal to 15 is not met, then img2 will not be defined. You then call `imshow` on an object which doesn't exist.

I have edited the below code to only call the imshow commands if the if condition is met, or to print an error.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
myVid = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
imgTarget = cv2.imread("TargetImage.jpg")

success, imgVideo = myVid.read()
hT, wT, cT = imgTarget.shape
imgVideo = cv2.resize(imgVideo, (wT, hT))

orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=200)

kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(imgTarget, None)

while True:
    success, imgWebcam = cap.read()
    imgAug = imgWebcam.copy()
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(imgWebcam, None)

    bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
    matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)
    good = []
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance:
            good.append(m)
    print(len(good))

    imgFeatures = cv2.drawMatches(imgTarget, kp1, imgWebcam, kp2, good, None, flags=2)

    if len(good) > 15:
        srcPts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        dstPts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        matrix, mask = cv2.findHomography(srcPts, dstPts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
        print(matrix)

        pts = np.float32([[0,0],[0,hT],[wT,hT],[wT,0]]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,matrix)
        
        img2 = cv2.polylines(imgWebcam,[np.int32(dst)],True,(255,0,255),3, cv2.LINE_AA)

        cv2.imshow('img2', img2)
        cv2.imshow('ImgFeatures', imgFeatures)
        cv2.imshow('ImgTarget', imgTarget)
        cv2.imshow('myVid', imgVideo)
        cv2.imshow('Webcam', imgWebcam)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

    else:
        print('Condition not met to show image')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I found it wasn't working because of the size of the image I was using, that's why the conditions of if len(good) > 15: couldn't be met. Thanks to your code I was able to run and find the problem in the m.distance <0.75